# Wordpress editor converted/deleted HTML entities code

Tags: editor

2x WP 4.9.1 (old and updated with database utf8 / new with new database utf8mb4)

I have a problem with HTML entities in the Wordpress standard editor.

I write the HTML entities in hexadecimal code in the editors Text mode and when I switch from Text mode to Visual mode and back to the Text mode, the HTML entities are no longer displayed, but the plain text characters (in a new WordPress installation) or only spaces (in an older but updated WordPress installation).

When I press F5 on the keyboard, the saved text with the hex codes is displayed, when the text was before saved, otherwise, and that's the bigger problem, everything is gone.

Why or what converted/deleted the hexadecimal codes?

[image: wordpress HTML entities]
[image: wordpress HTML entities]